# angularjs kendo datasource data length zero

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to get my grid (created by angular directive) populated with data, but it is not populating.

Here's my grid declaration:

```
<div id="dayTypesGrid" kendo-grid k-options='dayTypesGridOptions'></div>
```

Here's code from my angular controller:

```
$scope.dayTypesGridOptions = {
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "description",
            fields: {
                description: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                numberOfDays: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 0} }
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "description",
        title: "Day Type"
    }, {
        field: "numberOfDays",
        title: "Number of Days"
    }]
};
```

So far so good. The grid is instantiated, and I see the two columns.  And my angular controller executes my data fetch call, and I store the result in an array $scope.viewModel.dayTypes.
Using the browser dev tools, I can see that $scope.viewModel.dayTypes indeed contains the array of 7 records.
I now want to display those 7 records in the grid, and I do so as follows:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({data: $scope.viewModel.dayTypes});
$('#dayTypesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource = ds;
```

After that last line of code, my grid still remains empty.  Using the browser dev tools, I see that ds.data.length is zero.

What am I missing?

Comment: The reason I'm binding to the array (and not to a datasource with a transport and read method call defined) is because that viewModel of which the dayTypes array property is part of, has a whole lotta other properties binding to other controls on the page.  So it's not a scenario in which the dataSource needs to go off and retrieve its own data with an http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [setDataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setDataSource) method:

`$('#dayTypesGrid').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(ds);`

Comment: That did it!! Dude you rock! Thanks a mil'

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in my project and this works for me.  Your mileage may vary because you're using data instead of a transport URL, but I noticed the structure of your grid configuration is a bit different than mine.  For example, I define the schema when I create my datasource:

```
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "url/to/my/service",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "results"
            }
        };

    var gridConfig: {
        dataSource: dataSource,
        rowTemplate: $templateCache.get("modules/reports/row.html"),
        height: 500,
        scrollable: true,
        groupable: true,
        filterable: true,
        pageable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        "columns": [
            {
                "field": "status",
                "title": "Status",
                "width": 200
            },
            {
                "field": "actions",
                "title": "Actions",
                "width": 200
            }
        ]
    }
};
```